# how to select number value by where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I will store "DONE", "PENDING", and "NUMBER_TYPE " in the `status` column

but I have no idea how to make the query clause,

```
  scope :running, -> { where( " status <> HOW_TO_FILL ").order('created_at DESC') }
```

Comment: Is running numbers between `1` and `20000`?

Comment: do you want to select any record with `status` between `1` and `20000`?

Comment: no the number is `pid`. but i think it should between 1-20000 in most case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your possible statuses are `DONE`, `PENDING` or a number in string format, and that a status of `:running` equates to one of the numbers rather than the status `DONE` or `PENDING`, then the following should work:

```
scope :running, -> { where "status not in ('DONE', 'PENDING')" }
```

Of course, if you then introduced another non-number status, that would be treated as `RUNNING` unless you updated this scope to include the new status.

Another way to solve this would be to use the status `RUNNING`, and simply select that:

```
scope :running, -> { where status: 'RUNNING' }
```

Or even better, pass in a variable:

```
scope :with_status, ->(status) { where status: status.to_s.upcase }
```

Since we call `.to_s` and `.upcase` on the argument, you could pass in a symbol `:done` or a string of any case (`done`, `Done`, `DONE`) and they'd all work fine.
You could then use this scope as follows (I've assumed your model is called `Process`):

```
@running_processes = Process.with_status(:running)
```

Then you'd probably want to add a `running_pid` attribute to the model and store the integer value for the process when running there.